# How to print only first column of html table using JSOUP?

Tags: html, jsoup

I want to print the first column of html table,

For eg, i need to print the serial numbers only, or college names only.

[Image Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7TNb.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jkhighereducation.nic.in/colleges.html").get();
           
    
        Element table = doc.select("table").get(3);
        Elements tr = table.select("tr");

        for (int i = 0; i < tr.size(); i++) {
                Element fila = tr.get(i);
                Elements cols = fila.select("td");                                       
                System.out.println(cols.text());
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting table cell data, I find the `:nth-child(n)` selector is useful. To get the first column, use `td:nth-child(1)`, the second `td:nth-child(2)`, and so-on.

Here's a worked example:

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jkhighereducation.nic.in/colleges.html").get();
Elements elements = doc.select("div:containsOwn(Colleges of Jammu & Kashmir) ~  div td:nth-child(2)");
for (Element el : elements) {
    System.out.println(el.text());
}
```

Produces:

```
A.S. College
S.P. College
IASE, Srinagar (College of Education)
Govt. Women College M. A. Road Srinagar
Govt. Women College Nawakadal Srinagar
Govt. Degree College Bemina
...
```

I used this [try.jsoup](https://try.jsoup.org/%7EBrQaQUl5pUlZQ8vzMKspsBih6LY) to work out the selector. Also see the full [jsoup CSS Query](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) documentation.